# Flask is not detecting the trailing backslash in the URLS

Tags: python, flask

So I have used this to create a route

```
@app.route('/hi')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"`
```

But now if I go to **mydomain.com/hi** is works good but if I go to **mydomain.com/hi/** it throws a 404 error. Any idea?

Comment: use `"/hi/"` and it will work. Normally `'/hi'` and `'/hi/'` should be treated as different urls and Flask treats them as different urls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using

```
@app.route('/hi/')
def hello():
    return "Hello World"
```

As trailing `/` is also included in the url and if you use `/hi/` flask will take care of `/hi` as well